# Galilean Invariance of Navier Stokes Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

I'm struggling to work out some simple formalism. I'm reading something that says if the quadruple $(v_i(x_i,t),p(x_i,t))$ solves the navier stokes equations so does the quadruple $(v_i^c(x,t),p^c(x,t))$ given by $(v_i(x_i-c_it,t)+c_i,p(x_i-c_it,t))$. I've assumed here $i$ ranges from 1 to 3. For the divergence condition, I work out the following. Letting $x_i' = x_i-c_it$ we have:

$$\sum_i \frac{\partial v^c_i}{\partial x'_i} = \sum_i \frac{\partial v^c_i}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x'_i} = \sum_i \frac{\partial v^c_i}{\partial x_i}  = \sum_i \frac{\partial v_i(x_i-c_it,t)+c_i}{\partial x_i}$$

I want to conclude $$\sum_i \frac{\partial v^c_i}{\partial x'_i} = 0$$ but I'm getting stuck. I probably need to use $$\sum_i \frac{\partial v_i(x,t)}{\partial x_i} = 0$$ but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You’re basically done (you forgot some brackets on top of the d/dxi). Derivative of a constant is 0 so you can ignore the second term. Then use the identity given for v which holds for all x,t

Comment: @CalvinKhor 1. Where are brackets missing? Sorry -- I don't see this. 2. Ahh, yes, the divergence condition is zero for all points in the vector field! thanks!

Comment: What I meant was: the $\frac{\partial v_i (x_i - c_i t,t) + c_i}{\partial x_i}$ should be $\frac{\partial (v_i (x_1 - c_1t, \dots, x_n - c_n t,t) + c_i)}{\partial x_i}$. You're welcome!